# Periodic Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

A tricky problem I've found amongst past papers for a class I'm taking.

**Problem**

Show that the differential equation

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{dx}{dt}+\epsilon \bigg(\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)^3+\sin(x)=0$$

has no periodic solution if $\epsilon$ is positive.

**Thoughts**

I think this is probably an application of [Bendixson-Dulac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) for plane autonomous systems, but I can't establish how to manipulate the equation into a form to which we can apply B-D. Equally, it may call upon something different (although forcing a constant positivity for $\epsilon$ strongly suggests it isn't). Any assistance is appreciated. Regards as always, MM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x(t)$ is a solution periodic of period $T>0$. Multiply the equation by $x'(t)$ and integrate between $0$ and $T$. Since
$$
\int_0^Tx''(t)x'(t)dt=\frac12\,(x'(t))^2\Bigr|_0^T=0\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_0^T\sin(x(t))x'(t)dt=\cos(x(t))\Bigr|_0^T=0,
$$
we get
$$
\int_0^T\bigl((x'(t))^2+\epsilon\,(x'(t))^4 \bigr)dt=0,
$$
so that $x'(t)\equiv0$ and $x(t)$ is constant. Thus, the only *periodic* solutions are the stationary solutions $x(t)=k\,\pi$.