# Existence of a periodic solution from differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show the existence of a periodic solution for the following equations. Find the region in the plane where your result holds.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= -x^5 + 4y - 4x^2y
\end{align*}
$$

After I substitute $y=x'$ into equation 2, isn't that the Lienard equation and we can go through the different qualifications to test if everything checks off?

The first part is checking if $f(x) = -4x^2$ is positive, which it is.

Second is checking if $F(x)<0$ for $0 < x < "a"$ and $F(x)>0$ for $x > "a"$. I found "a" to be 0 when I solved for "a" in $f(x)$. How does that work in this case? What conclusion can be made?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Substitute $y = x'$ into the second equation to get differential equation in terms of just $x$ and its derivatives.

Comment: CAN SOMEBODY FOR THE LOVE OF GOD HELP ME PLEASE!

Comment: Making the substitution $y  = x'$ gives $x'' + 4(1 - x^2)x' + x^5 = 0$. Are you given any initial conditions i.e. values of $x(0)$ and $y(0)$?

Comment: Nope, everything is given

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98477/periodic-solutions?rq=1. It is possible that the only periodic solutions are the constants $x(t) = y(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: That's going into integrals and my professor didn't do any of that. I have no idea what's going on in that explanation.

Comment: Since $x(t) = y(t) = 0$ is one solution, then the answer will include the point (0,0) and may include other points.

Comment: Where is t coming from?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$ since the derivatives are given with respect to $t$

Comment: I noticed this is a Lienard equation. When you substitued, how did you know that the result is equal to 0?

Comment: Where did x'' come from?

Comment: Suppose that $x(t)$ is a constant. Then $x' = x'' = 0$. From there you can conclude that $x = 0$ if $x$ is a constant.

Comment: The $x''$ came from differentiating the first equation with respect to $t$.

Comment: After you differentiated it, you substituted it?

Comment: Yes - into the 2nd equation

Comment: Can you show it on here because I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate both sides of the first equation with respect to $t$:

$\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{dx}{dt}) = \frac{d}{dt} y$

$x''(t) = y'(t)$

Substitute the above expression into the second equation:

$x''(t) = -x^5 + 4y-4x^2y$ [1]

Then substitute the first equation you were given into [1]:

$x''(t) = -x^5 + 4x'(t) - 4x^2 x'(t)$

Simplify:

$x''(t) + x^5 + 4x^2 x' - 4x' = 0$

Factorise:

$x'' + 4(x^2 - 1)x' + x^5 = 0$ [4]

Now assume that $x(t)$ is some constant.

Then $x'(t) = 0$ and $x''(t) = 0$.

Substitute $x' = 0$ and $x'' = 0$ into [4]:

$0 + 4(x^2 - 1)0 + x^5 = 0$

$x^5 = 0$

$x = 0$

So if $x(t)$ is a constant, then $x(t) = 0$.

From the first equation, if $x = 0$, then $x' = 0$, so $y = 0$.

So (0,0) is part of the region in the plane where the solution is periodic.

[There may be other solutions as well.]

Comment: ok the math itself makes sense. How do you know that the solution is periodic? I'm sorry to ask all of these questions, my professor didn't do that great of a job explaining this.

Comment: There might be other solutions but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: That's ok, this is the perfect explanation that I needed. Is this the solution the same as a critical point?

Comment: The solution $x = y = 0$ is periodic since all constant functions are periodic. The term 'critical point' has a few different meanings in maths, but I don't think that this solution is the critical point, it is just one solution of the differential equation.

Comment: Ok now that makes sense. Unfortunately, my professor doesn't give enough examples and homework problems for me to practice so I'm reliant on this site and asking a lot of questions to get a solid understanding. Thank you for your help.